# Fill color in single cells in a networkx graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I've build a graph with networkx, that looks like this: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiI7F.png)

I want to fill every singel cell with a specified color. The Graph was drawn by nx.draw_networkx_edges() (returns a LineCollection). I found a similar question here ([Fill area between lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320510/is-there-any-way-to-fill-area-between-points)), but the solution in the comments, doesn't worked for me.

I've also used plt.fill_between with a simpler graph and manually set the values:

```
plt.fill_between([1, 2], [2, 2], color='yellow')
plt.fill_between([1.75, 2, 3], [1.25, 2, 2], color='purple')
plt.fill_between([0, 1, 1.25], [2, 2, 1.25], color='red')
plt.fill_between([0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25], [0.75, 1.25, 1.25, 0.75], color='blue')
plt.fill_between([2, 2.25, 3], [0, 0.75, 1], color='pink')
plt.fill_between([0, 0.75, 1], [1, 0.75, 0], color='green')
```

And it turns out pretty good ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwusA.png)), but the problem with that is, that the filling depends on the order when the cells get filled and that would make the algorithm for it way to complicated, I guess.

Does anyone knows a better and simpler solution?

Edit:
I tried to convert the Graph into a Voronoi-Diagram to try the solution of @JohanC, but the runtime is pretty long and the solution for larger graphs isn't exact. For the calculation of the centroids I used this [Center of Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732437/center-of-mass-in-voronoi-cells)

```
def find_Centroid(v):
    sum_A = 0
    sum_x = 0
    sum_y = 0
    for i in range(len(v)):
        next = i+1 if i != len(v)-1 else 0
        sum_A += v[i][0]*v[next][1] - v[next][0]*v[i][1]
        sum_x += (v[i][0] + v[next][0]) * (v[i][0]*v[next][1] - v[next][0]*v[i][1])
        sum_y += (v[i][1] + v[next][1]) * (v[i][0]*v[next][1] - v[next][0]*v[i][1])
    A = 1/2 * sum_A
    Cx = 1/(6*A) * sum_x
    Cy = 1/(6*A) * sum_y

    return Cx, Cy

# Get all cells of Graph (I think that takes most of the time)
cycle = nx.minimum_cycle_basis(SVG)

centroids = list()

# calculate all centroids of the cells
for c in cycle:
    subG = SVG.subgraph(c)
    sortedCycle = sortGraphNodes(subG)
    centroid = find_Centroid(sortedCycle)
    SVG.add_node((centroid[0], centroid[1]))
    centroids.append(centroid)

vor = Voronoi(centroids)
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

[Result small graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTOBR.png)
[Result large graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpOSk.png)

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515554/colorize-voronoi-diagram ?

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for the advice. I tried to convert my Graph into a Voronoi-Diagram and for smaller Graphs it worked good, but for bigger Graphs it takes a couple of minutes. I will Edit my question with this try. Maybe you have an idea what I can do different?

Comment: It would really help if you'd include a fully reproducible example. Can you elaborate what you mean by *"the solution for larger graphs isn't exact"*?  Why is the formula for the centroid dividing by 6, wouldn't dividing by the number of points be more logical?

Comment: Maybe you can use [matplotlib.tri.Triangulation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/tri_api.html#module-matplotlib.tri) or [scipy.spatial.Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) to find the triangles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the first code block from the question that shows filling the simpler graph, I constructed an example network.
The edges are listed below:

```
edges = [((1, 2), (2, 2)),
         ((1, 2), (0, 2)),
         ((1, 2), (1.25, 1.25)),
         ((2, 2), (1.75, 1.25)),
         ((2, 2), (3, 2)),
         ((1.75, 1.25), (1.25, 1.25)),
         ((1.75, 1.25), (2.25, 0.75)),
         ((3, 2), (3, 1)),
         ((0, 2), (0, 1)),
         ((1.25, 1.25), (0.75, 0.75)),
         ((0.75, 0.75), (0, 1)),
         ((0.75, 0.75), (1, 0)),
         ((2.25, 0.75), (2, 0)),
         ((2.25, 0.75), (3, 1)),
         ((2, 0), (1, 0)),
         ((2, 0), (3, 0)),
         ((3, 1), (3, 0)),
         ((0, 1), (0, 0)),
         ((1, 0), (0, 0))]
```

With this network, we do not need to use any Voronoi
diagram (although very pleasing to they eye) to fill
the cells of the network.

The basis for the solution is to use the minimum cycle
basis iterator for the network, and then correct each
cycle for following actual edges in the network (see
[documentation for minimum cycle basis](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.minimum_cycle_basis.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.minimum_cycle_basis)
"nodes are not necessarily returned in a order by
which they appear in the cycle").

The solution becomes the following, assuming `edges`
from above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
for edge in edges:
    G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

pos = {x: x for x in G.nodes}
options = {
    "node_size": 10,
    "node_color": "lime",
    "edgecolors": "black",
    "linewidths": 1,
    "width": 1,
    "with_labels": False,
}
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, **options)

# Fill all cells of graph
for cycle in nx.minimum_cycle_basis(G):
    full_cycle = cycle.copy()
    cycle_path = [full_cycle.pop(0)]
    while len(cycle_path) < len(cycle):
        for nb in G.neighbors(cycle_path[-1]):
            if nb in full_cycle:
                idx = full_cycle.index(nb)
                cycle_path.append(full_cycle.pop(idx))
                break
    plt.fill(*zip(*cycle_path))
plt.show()
```

The resulting graph looks like this:
[image: Simpler graph with filled cells]

This algorithm scales better than the Voronoi / centroid
approach listed in the edit to the question, but suffers
from the same inefficiencies for large networks (O(m^2n),
according to the reference in the
[documentation for minimum cycle basis](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.minimum_cycle_basis.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.minimum_cycle_basis)).

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. I've manged to find out the cycles while creating my Graph, so the inefficiencies are not a problem anymore.

Comment: Hi @blueberryhill, if you like my answer, please accept it as the best answer, and also vote it up.

Comment: I've accept your answer as the best, but I couldn't vote it up, because I've less than 15 reputations.